# How to bind static dropdownlist on gridview edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I want to place a static dorpdownlist to EditItemTemplate of the GridView.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtSuppstatus" Width="40px" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Suppstatus") %>' />--%>     
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSuppstatus" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Eval("Suppstatus") %>'>
         <asp:ListItem Text="YES" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="NO" Value="N"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

When page will load YES or NO option will show as a text but when user will edit the row on click on Edit it will show dorpdownlist with YES and NO option.

Dropdownlist is binding on edit but i am loosing all the data at the time of edit.

I have gone through to this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1587128.aspx?DropDownList%20in%20GridView%20Edit%20Mode%20Set%20Default%20Value) but facing the same problem. rest all the control is getting blank and dropdownlist is binding with YES and No option.

on page load

[image]

after edit

[image]

Please help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is working code:

Added OnRowDataBound:

```
    protected void grvSupplierStatus_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && grvSupplierStatus.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
            {
                DropDownList ddlSupStatus = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlSupstatus");
                Label lblsuppstatus = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblsuppStatus");                    
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = GetYesNoValue("suppStatus");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = ds.Tables[0];
                ddlSupStatus .DataSource = dt;
                ddlSupStatus .DataTextField = "suppStatus";
                ddlSupStatus .DataValueField = "suppStatus";
                ddlSupStatus .DataBind();
                ddlSupStatus.Items.FindByValue(lblsuppstatus.Text).Selected = true;

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
        }

    }
```

Added Generic Method

```
    public DataSet GetYesNoValue(string ColumnName)
    {
        DataTable dtVal = new DataTable();
        DataColumn column;
        DataRow row;

        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = ColumnName;
        dtVal.Columns.Add(column);

        DataSet dsVal = new DataSet();

        dtVal.Rows.Add("--Select--");
        dtVal.Rows.Add("Yes");
        dtVal.Rows.Add("No");

        dsVal.Tables.Add(dtVal);

        return dsVal;
    }
```

Added the label and dropdownlist inside the EditItemTemplate

```
<asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("Suppstatus") %>' Visible="false" ID="lblsuppStatus" runat="server" />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSupStatus"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an `ItemTemplate` field for the initial display, and a seperate `EditItemTemplate` for the dropdown list:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Suppstatus") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Eval("Suppstatus") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Text="YES" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="NO" Value="N"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: it is there I only copied the code from edititemtemplate

Comment: Ok then I'm not sure what you mean by **i am loosing all the data at the time of edit.** Could you eleborate a little on that?

Comment: I have multiple column with textbox on edit those textbox are filling while edit blank textbox is showing. when I am using textbox instead of dropdownlist it is showing all the data in all the textbox

Comment: You may need to post more of the gridview code, I dont understand the issue. Also if you had a screenshot that would help

Comment: Sorry I still dont see the problem. Consider adding all the gridview code.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever data needs to be sent back to database/server, such as for update purpose, you need to use the `Bind()` method and NOT the `Eval()` method.

`Bind()` method sends the data back to the datasource control, while `Eval()` method just reads the data.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtSuppstatus" Width="40px" runat="server"
      Text='<%#Bind("Suppstatus") %>' />--%>     
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSuppstatus" AutoPostBack="true" 
         runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("Suppstatus") %>'>
         <asp:ListItem Text="YES" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="NO" Value="N"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Using `Bind` in a GridView, DetailsView etc.. controls template such as: `EditItemTemplate` or `InsertItemTemplate`, enables the control to pass the modified values to the data source control.

The data source control performs the appropriate Update / Insert command for the database. For this reason, the `Bind` function is used inside the `EditItemTemplate` or `InsertItemTemplate` of a data-bound control.

Read [**`MSDN explanation here.`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)